# Jquery validate false set button false

Tags: jquery, button

recently ,I learn the Jquery to validate data in web. I used c# and B/S .
now ,I have create a login form with server control box. like

now I have finish the validate, but the submit button still can work if validate is failed.
**now I want to set submit disable when validate is failed.**

here is my a part of validate code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#username").blur(function () {
                var name = $("#username").val();
                if (name == "") {
                    $("#nameShow").html("*Please input name");
                    $("#nameShow").addClass("warning");
                }
                else {
                    $("#nameShow").html("");
                    $("#nameShow").removeClass("warning");
                }

            });

            $("#username").click(function () {
                //当按钮点击的时候执行下面的代码
                //找到页面上id为userName的文本框，并获取文本框内的值，用jquery提供的val方法
                var userName = $("#username").val();
                $("#nameShow").removeClass("warning");
                //判断userName的值是不是为空
                if (userName == "") {
                    //如果为空，提示用户
                    $("#nameShow").html("*please input your login name.*");
                }
                else {
                    $("#nameShow").html("");

                }

            });
```

**the c# Code:**

```
  <asp:Button ID="login_btn" CssClass="btn" runat="server" Text="登录" OnClick="login_btn_Click" />
```

if validate false, then button cannot to be trigger. I used this way ,but it only work in IE, when switch to google browser ,it still can trigger.

```
  $("#login_btn").submit(function () {
                var name = $("#username").val();
                var pass = $("#password").val();
                var code = $("#verifycode").val();
                if (name == "" || pass == "" || code == "") {
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    return true;
                }

            });
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: I was just answering [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20170284/c-sharp-pass-datetime-value-to-oracle-as-filter-paramters). If you haven't got the answer you could undelete and I will. If you have don't worry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS:

```
document.getElementById("login_btn").disabled=true;
```

JQuery:

```
$("#login_btn").attr("disabled", true);
```

See more here: [Submit disabled Property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_submit_disabled.asp)

If your button is an object, you can disable it like this:

```
submitButtonObject.disabled = true;
```

On valid form you can just change the attribute value from **true** to **false**.

Comment: when validate failed then I set the button is disable. how to associate with validate functions?

Comment: Just add those lines to if statements. @chengdu.jack

Comment: I have some events like blur or click , how to use if statements with this function events?

Comment: @chengdu.jack try   `if (name == "") {
                    $("#nameShow").html("*Please input name");
                    $("#nameShow").addClass("warning");
                    $("#login_btn").attr("disabled", true); 
                }
                else {
                    $("#nameShow").html("");
                    $("#nameShow").removeClass("warning");
                    $("#login_btn").attr("disabled", false); 
                }`

Comment: I need use blur or click event. when cursor focus on textbox or leap it ,then have show different message or color.

Comment: yes, I modified your if statement in blur event. give it a look.

Comment: Sorry, where did you modify, I did't see any changes.

Comment: ok, I see that , it seems can work , then ,the question that if have ten fields to validate, then we need to write so many time let button disable in different events. is that available?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

For Disable a Button

```
$('#YourButtonID').attr("disabled", true);
```

Enable

```
$('#YourButtonID').attr("disabled", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you can use something like this as well:

```
$("#login_btn").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var name = $("#username").val();
            var pass = $("#password").val();
            var code = $("#verifycode").val();
            if (name == "" || pass == "" || code == "") {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $('your form').submit();
                return true;
            }

        });
```

Comment: I use server control .  <form id="form1" runat="server">, is that can work, I try it and failed. just cannot find the submit() method